# CS5530 - Read serial data through SPI

Tags: arduino, adc, spi, serial, load-cell

I am trying to read data from a [CS5530](https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/CS5530_F3.pdf) using SPI.

I have gone through the complete datasheet but I don't understand what is missing. I am getting the same value every time even after changing the load on the load cell.

I have configured it to send data but I am getting the same data every time, even though the data is expected to vary with the load. I verified the wiring and tested the load cell: they are working fine. But I'm not getting the data on the Arduino's SPI.

"CS5530 -> SPI -> Arduino -> UART -> PC"

I tried multiple things but it's not working. Your help is appreciated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvjYVbm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: IMAGE OF MODULE]

````
#include<SPI.h>
#define SYNC1CMD 0xFF
#define SYNC0CMD 0xFE
#define SS 10
uint8_t b1, b2, b3, b4;
uint8_t b11, b12, b13, b14;
uint8_t b21, b22, b23, b24;
void setup (void)

{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(SS, OUTPUT);

  SPI.begin();
  //SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV8);
  SPI.beginTransaction (SPISettings (4000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));  // 4 MHz clock, MSB first, mode 0
  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(SYNC1CMD);
  SPI.transfer(SYNC0CMD);
  delayMicroseconds(100);
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);

}

void loop(void)
{

  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(0x03);
  delayMicroseconds(100);
  b1 = SPI.transfer(0x20);
  b2 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  b3 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  b4 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
//  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);

  delayMicroseconds(100);

//  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(0x03);
  delayMicroseconds(100);
  b11 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  b12 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  b13 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  b14 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
//  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);

  delayMicroseconds(100);

//  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(0x0B);
  delayMicroseconds(100);
  b21 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  b22 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  b23 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
  b24 = SPI.transfer(0x00);

  if ((b21 & 0x10) == 0x10)
  { //Valid Reset OCCUR
    delayMicroseconds(50);
    SPI.transfer(0x03);//Select Configuration Register
    SPI.transfer(0x00);//Write RV bit to Configuration Register
    SPI.transfer(0x00);
    SPI.transfer(0x00);
    SPI.transfer(0x00);
  }
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);

  delay(10);
  Serial.println("*****B1*****");
  Serial.println(b1);
  Serial.println(b2);
  Serial.println(b3);
  Serial.println(b4);
  Serial.println("*****B2*****");
  Serial.println(b11);
  Serial.println(b12);
  Serial.println(b13);
  Serial.println(b14);
  Serial.println("*****B3*****");
  Serial.println(b21);
  Serial.println(b22);
  Serial.println(b23);
  Serial.println(b24);
  Serial.println("*****########################*****");
}
```
````

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to re-read the CS5530 datasheet how the SPI interface works. There are tables and pictures that explain it in detail. Right now the code looks like it is not even meant to communicate with a CS5530 but maybe with something else.

The code does not have the required system initialization sequence, and even if it did, the command sent to the chip is write gain register while trying to read from the chip, so there is no start of conversion command sent, or other configuration register write to select a correct operating mode.

Comment: Sorry, Previously the code was not right. Now after changing the code the problem did not solve. The request for data command is 0x0B and the main problem remains the same. No variation in data.

Answer (score 1):

You make it sound like the ADC "sends" data. It does not.  The microcontroller (master)

- requests the ADC to be activated (by sending a serial stream on the spi bus specific to your ADC
- Once activated, the ADC listens to the next byte which is usually a register number where the requested data is stored (see the ADC datasheet)
- Then, the ADCs data is transferred with the following 8 clock cycles (per byte to be transferred.

More may be happening, like if multiple bytes are requested.  In the end, you need to read the datasheet snd realize that the Arduino is the master that makes requests, the ADC is the slave that responds to requests.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your review. Now I modified the code and requested register through the 0x0B command and using individual bytes but the problem is not resolved. Still getting the same data on repeatition.

Comment: Each SPI device need several startup/initialization commands. Check the datasheet. Read section 2.2 and 2.2.1 (to get started). 2.2.1 discusses the initialization.